# Any SVN like database solutions\librarys which are opensource and work OK with Java?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdo

I want to have my DB server opensource and capable of saving hystory of record changing. 
Meaning I do not want it to be way 2 complicated , I'd love to operate with it like with JDOs but with some kind of revision extention... or SQL like DB with extended sintax and search capabiletis... So is out there any such?

Comment: Um your question isn't very clear.  Are you writing your own Database Server?  I'm totally lost here.

Comment: why community wiki? Answerers will get less score for their answers (upvotes don't count for badges), not exactly a great way to motivate people. the topic isn't really a wiki one imho...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a solution backed by Hibernate providing history, it's called [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers), but from what I remember, there are some minor drawbacks.

There also is another solution : JCR. A Java Content Repository is a non-relationnal DB, that is far more compatible with your history needs (as it can use, as an example, a SVN repository as storage back-end). You can take a look at [modeshape](http://www.jboss.org/modeshape), as an example.

Comment: Envers is pretty solid these days, and is now part of the main Hibernate project. Definitely worth trying, especially if you're already using Hibernate for persistence.

Comment: I'm impressed that you interpreted his question :)